# Using .htaccess To Redirect URL With Parameters To URL With Paramters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been googling for a while trying to work out how to redirect the following url:

http://mysite.org/old-folder/?abc=1144

to a new URL:

http://mysite.org/new/folders/?xyz=1144

Where the number 1144 is dynamic.

I've got as far as this, but can't seem to get it working:

```
RewriteRule ^old-folder/\?abc=([0-9]+)(/)?$ new/folders/\?xyz=$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: For the x-th time: `RewriteRule` only looks at the _path_ component of the URL – if you want to check the _query string_, you have to use a `RewriteCond` …

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. In my incredibly limited knowledge of this, I thought that was only if you were looking for a particular value of a parameter in a query string, but I was wrong. I'd seen bad examples on other sites that didn't use RewriteCond for query strings if they were dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I have come up with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^abc=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^old-folder new/folders/?xyz=%1 [L,R=301]
```

If anyone else comes to this in the future, it will only match values for 'abc' that are numeric. If you want it to match anything, replace the first line with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^abc=(.*)$
```

For an explanation of the flags [L,R=301] see the apache docs:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

You cant match query string in `RewriteRule`.

Try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)abc=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^old-folder/$ new/folders/?xyz=%1 [L,NC]
```